# To get environmental variables in front end js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

In front end, we need to get environmental variables from .env file using node js - package.json file. while log in terminal we can see the value, but runtime while inspecting  it shows error.

Comment: Add some code snippets and error logs. Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this,  create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this. And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site. Goodluck :D